# Scraping emails from private Facebook groups

Tags: facebook, web, web-scraping

I want to scrape emails of the members of a particular group on Facebook but I cannot see them (the group is private) because I am not a member of the group and I would not accepted anytime soon.

Comment: Of course that is not possible.

Comment: the group is private and you are not a member - that means all the data is none of your business. even if you are a member, you cannot just scrape emails and do what you want with them. even storing them without specific user consent would not be allowed, so what is the use case for this?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem possible as private groups on Facebook ensure the confidentiality of their members. With Facebook under constant pressure to maintain user privacy I doubt this will become possible any time soon without joining the group.